# High availability in a generic parallel workload scenario

Tags: parallel-computing, high-performance-computing

Let's say I have a compute workload that is so large that it has to be spread between 10 identical server nodes, each with processors, memory, storage and network interfaces, and the workload requires a lot of traffic between these nodes. Now, suppose one of these nodes is down. In that case, the intermediate data and results that happened to be in that node are lost even if the node itself can be quickly brought back online using existing cloud features such as high availability, and therefore the whole compute cannot continue anymore even if everything is available again almost instantly.

Is there any theoretical way to automatically recover the whole compute in the above scenario *without* demanding the whole compute be rewritten as a series of transactions? Or going the way of N-way redundancy and voting on results?

Comment: It depends on the task you're trying to compute, and possibly also the probability of failure vs the time/cost for the system to come back up after failure.